# I want to call method in *delegate.m from C++

Tags: c++, facebook

I have a button written purely in c++;
but I need to call facebook connect ,since it is written in objective c.

so I wonnder if I could call the method written in *delegatel.m from c++.? if it`s ok,how?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the extension of your source file from `*.cpp` or `*.m` to `*.mm`, so it will compile as Objective-C++.  This means that it will be able to mix C++ and Objective C code in the same file.